# Python: APScheduler run sequences of jobs

Tags: python, sequence, apscheduler

I'am trying to make a scheduler for two tasks, which MUST be executed one after another. Unfortunately I'm not able to figure it out how to make it with apscheduler module.
The following code is some example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BBlockingScheduler()

def f1():
    print('start')
    print('stop')


def f2():
    print('start1')
    print('stop1')


sched.add_job(f1, 'cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=10, min=2)
sched.add_job(f2)
sched.start()
```

When I click "run" on the IDE, when the desired time is meet the code is executed, BUT the result is the following output:

```
start1
stop1
start
stop
```

Right now just to get the right sequences of executions, i made `f1` to call `f2`. But I believe that there is more pythonic way to do it. This 'solution' is not usefull and wrong is no many ways.

If anyone has faced this problem, I will be more then happy if you share your experience with me.
I tried some ideas from [Sequentially run pending tasks with Python APS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459382/sequentially-run-pending-tasks-with-python-aps) and from
[APScheduler:Trigger New job after completion of previous job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996869/apschedulertrigger-new-job-after-completion-of-previous-job), but I was not able to mange them.

Comment: Why don't you define a function f3 and call f1 and f2 within it? That easily solves your problem.

Comment: @Tanveer Indeed I did it...but Im looking for more 'clear' way to do it. Where I have some `add_job`, each independent one from other, but to be executed when the last one is finished.